# Reopened question gets marked double-closed

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

When voting to reopen a closed question through the moderator tools, the question is reopened and the title (in the moderator tools) has *another* [closed] appended to it:

[image]

[The question itself](https://superuser.com/questions/473225/is-there-any-way-to-pass-through-secure-boot-and-install-linux#question) doesn't have any suffix.

Comment: Looks like it got double plus unclosed